# ‘getnstimeofday' is an implicit declaration in system call when <linux/time.h> is included

Tags: c, linux-kernel, system-calls, gettimeofday

## Anwser

**Solved!! Thanks to @IanAbbott**

the header should be:

```
#include <linux/ktime.h>
#include <linux/timekeeping.h>
```

rather than `<linux/time.h>`.

More detail see discussion.

---

## Original Question

I am writing a system call names `sys_my_time.c`, which will use `getnstimeofday()`. I have imported `<linux/time.h>`. The code like this:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/linkage.h>
#include <linux/time.h>

asmlinkage int sys_my_time() {
  struct timespec t;
  getnstimeofday(&t);
  // ...
  return 0;
}
```

But while compiling, the error shows:

```
CC      kernel/sys_my_time.o
kernel/sys_my_time.c: In function ‘sys_my_time’:
kernel/sys_my_time.c:8:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘getnstimeofday’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
getnstimeofday(&t);
^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:320: recipe for target 'kernel/sys_my_time.o' failed
make[1]: *** [kernel/sys_my_time.o] Error 1
Makefile:1029: recipe for target 'kernel' failed
make: *** [kernel] Error 2
```

I have no idea why the error happens.

P.S. compiling kernel V4.14.25 in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Since v3.17.x, `getnstimeofday` is declared by `#include <linux/timekeeping.h>`.

Comment: @Abbott thanks, However when I change to `<linux/timekeeping.h>` and other the same: 
`In file included from kernel/sys_my_time.c:3:0:
./include/linux/timekeeping.h:19:36: warning: ‘struct timeval’ declared inside parameter list
 extern void do_gettimeofday(struct timeval *tv);
                                    ^
// ......

./include/linux/timekeeping.h:330:4: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘
kernel/sys_my_time.c: In function ‘sys_my_time’:
kernel/sys_my_time.c:7:18: error: storage size of ‘t’ isn’t known
  struct timespec t;`

Comment: Seems we cannot use `<linux/timekeeping.h>` directly? The error message are not likely caused by me code?

Comment: It maybe depends on some other headers. Try `#include <linux/ktime.h>` instead as that will do a nested #include of `<linux/timekeeping.h>` and other time-related headers.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thanks!! After adding `#include <linux/ktime.h>
#include <linux/timekeeping.h>`, it is just fine. :)

Comment: @Ian Abbott Could you paste in answer, and I could mark it as the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since kernel version 3.17.x, `getnstimeofday` is no longer declared by `#include <linux/time.h>`. The solution is to add:

```
#include <linux/ktime.h>
```

Depending on the kernel version, `#include <linux/ktime.h>` will pull in the declaration of `getnstimeofday` from either `<linux/time.h>` (prior to 3.17.x) or from `<linux/timekeeping.h>` (for 3.17.x onwards). There is no need to include `<linux/timekeeping.h>` directly.

Note that `<linux/ktime.h>` has been available since Linux kernel 2.6.16 onwards.

You may be able to remove your `#include <linux/time.h>` if there is nothing else in there you need to use. Test that by removing the line and building your code for any kernel 3.17.x or later.